# removeEventListener of anonymous function bind

Tags: javascript, dom, this, bind

I need help removing an EventListener on an anonymous function. I tried using an event handler but I also need to pass a element through the function to bind it.

```
// adds eventlistener to element
cardElement.addEventListener("click", flipCard.bind(this, cardElement));

// suppose to remove eventlistener
document.getElementById(cardsInPlay[0].id).removeEventListener("click", flipCard);
```

Answer (score 3):

`bind` creates a new function, as you can read from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

So what you can do is something like:

```
flipCard = flipCard.bind(this, cardElement);
cardElement.addEventListener("click", flipCard);
document.getElementById(cardsInPlay[0].id).removeEventListener("click", flipCard);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a different method to remove the event listener. I deep cloned the node and replaced it.

```
var matchOne = cardOne.cloneNode(true);
cardOne.parentNode.replaceChild(matchOne, cardOne);
```